# Javascript: How can I use object properties in functions using the parameter?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner to Javascript and I am trying to make a text-based game for practice. I have made objects for enemies like so:

```
export const spider = {
strength: 1,
health: 4,
gold: 1
};
```

I am now trying to make a function which can search for their stats when their name is entered in the field. It looks like this:

```
export const findStats = (target) => {
return target.health;
}
```

However, when I do this and test it I get 'undefined.' However, if I replace 'target.health' with 'spider.health' it works properly.

The error occurs when I try doing findStats("spider") which gives me the 'undefined results.'

Any help would be appreciated. Note: I did look around this site but found the threads too complex or not quite what I was looking for. I am a beginner so simple terms would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks for all your comments!

My issue is unlike to the one on the right as when I try it with my code is still returns 'undefined.' Here is the code that I have just tried using the other thread. Keep in mind I am a beginner so I am probably doing it very wrong but if you could help further I would be very happy.

```
export const findLocalStats = (target) => {
  var bar = 'strength';
  console.log(target[bar]);
}
```

Here are is my test command:

```
expect(findLocalStats("spider")).toEqual(1);
```

Furthermore, when I tried the code written in JSFiddle in my editor, it still gave the same error in the terminal which is 'undefined.'

```
export function findStats(target) {
return target.strength;
}
```

And the test command:

```
expect(findStats("spider")).toEqual(1);
```

And the exact error message:

findStats() gives the stats of the target wanted.

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected)

Expected value to equal:
  1
Received:
  undefined

Difference:

  Comparing two different types of values. Expected number but received undefined.
```

Sorry if this is very tedious.
Note 2: I posted this question before but I have changed it to attempt to explain my issue better as I still do not understand the answers I was given and the links to duplicate questions - which I have tried to replicate. Furthermore, the duplicate that I was given was different. It used the object as the keyword, however I want to use it as a feed-in to a parameter so that it is versatile for more than one enemies if that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: You're giving it a string, which doesn't have a health field. Just give `spider`,don't wrap it in quotes when you pass it.

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling findStats like this : `findStats("spider")` you are sending a string to the function as an argument. That's why when it tries to get the property *health* it says **undefined**.

You need to give the function an instance of your *spider* object. To create an instance you can use the **Object.create()** method like `var killMe = Object.create(spider)`. This will create a new object based on the one you declared before. Then you can call your function like this : `findStats(killMe)`

You can find an exemple here : https://jsfiddle.net/10ex1xqt/